# Flask views not working properly after changing the position of the view in the file

Tags: python, flask

When I requested tag_list view the posts variable didn't list out the data.
And after changing its position above self_entries view, everything worked fine. 
But now I cannot get self_entries view data.
What I am missing here? 
After changing the position everything falls as expected but the view which lies at the bottom doesn't display the data at all.

## more views at the top

```
@app.route('/entries')
@login_required
def list():
    posts = models.Journal.select().order_by(models.Journal.created_at.desc())
    return render_template("entries.html", posts=posts)

# This View Works as expected
@app.route('/entries/<username>')
@login_required
def self_entries(username):
    posts = (models.Journal
    .select(models.User, models.Journal)
    .join(models.User)
    .where(models.User.username**username)
    .order_by(models.Journal.created_at.desc())
    )
    # for post in posts:
    #     print(post.title + str(post.created_at.date()) + post.tag)
    return render_template("entries.html", posts=posts)

# This view doesn't... the page displays as empty
@app.route('/entries/<tag>')
@login_required
def tag_list(tag):
    posts = (models.Journal
    .select()
    .where(models.Journal.tag == tag)
    .order_by(models.Journal.created_at.desc())
    )
    return render_template("entries.html", posts=posts)
```

## more views at the bottom

entries.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ hi }}</h1>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <article>
                <h2><a href="{{ url_for('detail', slug=post.slug ) }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <time datetime="{{ post.created_at }}">{{ post.created_at.date() }}</time>
                <h3><a href="{{ url_for('tag_list', tag=post.tag) }}" >{{ post.tag }}</a><h3>
            </article>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. Both the route below are using the similar API ie. '/entries/', so there is a conflict. so change either one.

```
@app.route('/entries/<username>')
@app.route('/entries/<tag>')
```

changed `@app.route('/entries/<tag>')` to `@app.route('/entry/<tag>')` it works.